# Android drawer selector state_activated doesn't work and doesn't coloring defeault selected item

Tags: android, selector, drawerlayout, navigation-drawer

I am struggling with this terrible bug. It seems that everything works instead this one `android:state_activated`. I was trying to put `<item>` in different order but it doesn't help. In addition, when the app starts the default chosen fragment option in the drawer is not colored too (as it was in default version)...

This is my `selector`:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@color/colorPirmaryDarkerGray"
          android:state_activated="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@color/colorPirmaryDarkerGray"
          android:state_pressed="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@android:color/transparent"/>
</selector>
```

This is the layout for one item:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="horizontal"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"
            android:id="@+id/itemIcon"/>
    <TextView
            android:id="@android:id/text1"
            android:duplicateParentState="true"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="32sp"
            />

</LinearLayout>
```

This is drawer layout:

```
<ListView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
          android:paddingTop="10dp"
          android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
          android:dividerHeight="0dp"
          android:background="#cccc"
          android:drawSelectorOnTop="false"
          android:listSelector="@drawable/my_drawer_selector"
          tools:context="com.myPackage.app.NavigationDrawerFragment"/>
```

This is on `onCreateView` (I added here my own adapter only, the rest is default)

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        mDrawerListView = (ListView) inflater.inflate(
                R.layout.drawer_dashboard, container, false);
        mDrawerListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                selectItem(position);
            }
        });
        String[] items = {
                getString(R.string.Contacts),
                getString(R.string.Data)
        };

        Integer[] images = {
                R.drawable.ic_contacts,
                R.drawable.ic_data
        };
        mDrawerListView.setAdapter(new MyCustomDrawerListAdapter(getActivity(), items, images));

//This should indicate the first coloring but it doesn't
        mDrawerListView.setItemChecked(mCurrentSelectedPosition, true);
        return mDrawerListView;
    }
```

And in the end, my `MyCustomDrawerListAdapter`:

```
private class MyCustomDrawerListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String>{
        private final Activity context;
        private final String[] itemname;
        private final Integer[] imgid;

        public MyCustomDrawerListAdapter(Activity context, String[] itemname, Integer[] imgid){
            super(context, R.layout.my_menu_drawer_item, itemname);
            this.context = context;
            this.itemname = itemname;
            this.imgid = imgid;
            for (Integer anImgid : imgid) {
                System.out.println(" image id " + anImgid);
            }
        }
        public View getView(int position,View view,ViewGroup parent) {
            if (view == null) {
                view = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.my_menu_drawer_item, null, false);
            }

            ((TextView) view.findViewById(android.R.id.text1))
                    .setText(getItem(position));
            ((ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.itemIcon))
                    .setImageResource(imgid[position]);
            return view;

        }

    }
```

Comment: What version are you targetting and what version are you testing on?

Comment: Targeting 25, testing on 21

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had some issues when running on api 21 devices.

The way I solved the probles was:

In the `ListView` set as background the highlight color (colorAccent in my case).

```
android:background="@color/colorAccent"
```

and also set the`ListView` selector to:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
        <solid android:color="@color/colorAccent"/>
</shape>
```

For the drawer item, set the `LinearLayout` top level container background to

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@android:color/transparent" android:state_selected="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@android:color/transparent" android:state_pressed="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@android:color/transparent" android:state_activated="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@color/colorMenuBackground"/>
</selector>
```

In my case:

```
<color name="colorMenuBackground">#FFFFFF</color>
```

To select the first item, in onPostCreate() of your main activity run:

```
setItemChecked(0,true);
```

on the listview (0 is the position of the item)

In fact this is how I have that method that also syncs with the Hamburguer menu button:

```
@Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Sync the toggle state after onRestoreInstanceState has occurred.
        actionBarDrawerToggle.syncState();
        drawerList.setItemChecked(1,true);

    }
```

Comment: I don't know how but it works! But when the app is starting none of the drawers items is colored :(

Comment: In my case I have it like that but, I guess you can call selectItem(position); at the end of onCreateView to select an item of the list. Also I have found that there is some bug in the emulator, that doesn't render well the option view when the app is started but it doesn't happen on real devices.

Comment: Sorry, see if besides of checked you can set the view to selected.

Comment: I'm testing on the real device. I can set the view to selected but I noticed that it "stays" selected even if I move my finger and doesn't choose the option

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a new package name color inside the res folder, inside the color package create your my_drawer_selector file

then use this file with

```
"@color/my_drawer_selector"
```

This need to be like this :

[image]

nav_item_state_list is your my_drawer_selector

Comment: Do you mean I need to put my drawer into colors in values? Why?

Comment: No you really need to create a new package name it color inside the res folder and then inside it put your xml file. I know this seem to be strange but this it how it works

Comment: right click on res folder -> new -> android ressource directory. Name it color. Inside it create a xml file and put your selector code

Comment: I have my `my_drawer_selector.xml` in the drawable folder which is in res

Comment: Yes but you need to create a ressource directory name color not colors inside your res folder not in your values folder. Yes I know that it is in drawable and this is why it doesn't work

Comment: How it should look like? Can you update your answer? Especially in case my code

Comment: @soommy12 He is answering correct you have to create a folderunder resources with name color